# why javascript function does not print

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testGenerator() {
        yield "first";
        document.write("step1");
        yield "second";
        document.write("step2");
        yield "third";
        document.write("step3");
    }
    var g = testGenerator();
    document.write(g.next());
    document.write(g.next());
</script>
```

Why does the function print nothing?

Answer (score 3):

First, check [this chart](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/) to make sure the browser you are using supports yield.

Then, check [Mozilla's section on iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generators.3A_a_better_way_to_build_Iterators), or just read the main points quoted below:

> In order to use some of the new features of JavaScript 1.7, you need to specify that you wish to use JavaScript 1.7. In HTML or XUL code, use:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"></script>
```

> When using the JavaScript shell, you need to set the version you wish to use using the -version 170 switch on the command line or using the version() function:

```
version(170);
```

> The features that require the use of the new keywords "yield" and "let" require you to specify version 1.7 because existing code might use those keywords as variable or function names. The features that do not introduce new keywords (destructuring assignment and array comprehensions) can be used without specifying the JavaScript version.

TL;DR: The yield keyword is only available to code blocks in HTML wrapped in a `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">`